# How to make chocolate cigarellos in a quicker way?

Tags: chocolate, decorating

I wanted to make chocolate cigarellos from scratch and looked it up but all I could find was [this](http://cakecentral.com/article173-how-to-make-chocolate-cigarellos-natis-way.html), which the author describes as being time consuming. Can someone suggest any other way to make them that might be quicker?

Comment: They are going to be fundamentally time consuming to make, especially without automated equipment.  You can buy them ready made from various sources.  One example:  http://www.chocolatetradingco.com/buy/dark-chocolate-cigarellos

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: I was wondering if someone has tried to make them in plastic straws and how would you make the ends from being runny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is use much longer pieces of acetate and cut the long cigarillos afterwards gently with a hot knife.  That way your spreading and rolling action is cut down to 1/2 or 1/3.